# Why does bash dispatch DEBUG signal after the script exit?

Tags: bash

I am learning DEBUG signal of bash.

The followings are my test code to regenerate the phenomenon of my question. So it does not have much meaning. Please don't care details.
 It prepares two traps, one is called by EXIT signal to clean up temporal script originally but it is a dummy function here. And the second one is called by DEBUG signal to calculate the line where the debugger is scanning.
 My question is DEBUG signal may be dispached at clean_up_debugger with LINENO = 0. Why is the LINENO 0 at that time? I add detail of my question after following output by bash -x. Please tell me why it happens.
 Thank you very much.

```
#!/bin/bash
# file name is debug.working

source "bash_debugger_functions.sh"

trap clean_up_debugger_func EXIT

no_of_line_until_here=${LINENO}  # *** no_of_line_until_here is 12 ***
trap "show_line_scanned \$(( \${LINENO} - ${no_of_line_until_here} - 1 ))" DEBUG
#!/bin/bash

echo "echo_sring = $1"
```

The following is a library file

```
#!/bin/bash 
# file name is 'bash_debugger_functions.sh'

clean_up_debugger_func() {
  echo "dummy"
}

show_line_scanned() {
  echo "At line $1"
}
```

The following is a part of output by bash -x debug.working

```
+ (debug.working:17): echo 'echo_sring = test_message'
++ (debug.working:1): show_line_scanned -12
```

Just after "echo 'echo_sring = test_message'" is called, show_line_scanned is called with negative value, -12. no_of_line_until_here is +12. So it seems LINENO is 0 at that time. I don't know why the show_line_scanned is called here because I supposed that DEBUG signal is dispatched at each line but there is no new line after "echo "echo_sring = $1"". And I would like to know why LINENO is 0 here.
Please teach me the mechanism here.

Answer (score 0):

> I supposed that DEBUG signal is dispatched at each line but there is no new line after "echo "echo_sring = $1"".

Still there is a line executed after the last line of your `debug.working` script, because you set up the `trap clean_up_debugger_func EXIT` command, and for that `clean_up_debugger_func` command you get the DEBUG command dispatch which puzzles you.

> And I would like to know why LINENO is 0 here.

The execution of the script has just ended at this time, and `man bash` states about `LINENO`:

> When  not  in  a
>                 script  or  function, the value substituted is not guaranteed to
>                 be meaningful.